# How can I skip the first if statement occuring in a loop?

Tags: php

I have made a loop to print table `<tr>` and `<td>`
Here is my code:

```
 echo "<tr>";
 for($i = 0; $i < (int)count($fieldvalues); $i++){
 echo "<td>" . $fieldvalues[$i] . "</td>";
 if($i % 4 == 0){
 echo "<td><input type='text'></td><td><input type='submit' 
 value='Add to cart'></td></form></tr>";
                } 
 }
```

I want to skip the first `if` statement in the loop because the condition `$i % 4== 0` is true when $i is 0, that is, `0 % 4 == 0`.The value of `$fieldvalues` is 8. Any other method to overcome this is much appreciated.

Comment: `if(expression) continue;`

Comment: Aside from the loop-if problem, you also need to address the colspan problem of your td tag, on which doesn't have the last td.

Comment: no `<form>` tag, one `<tr>`, and the possibility of _zero_, one or _many_ `</tr>` and `</form>` tags are just asking for trouble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that it is not `0` in the conditional.

```
if(!empty($i) && $i % 4 == 0){
```

or

```
if($i != 0 && $i % 4 == 0){
```

I'd also use a `foreach` rather than `for`.

A demo: https://3v4l.org/bG2NS

Comment: Isn't `if(!$i && ....` enough? You don't need to compare against 0 or if it's empty.

Comment: @Andreas Yea, I prefer the written out though, `!= 0` is easier to know what the developer was expecting. The `empty` wont through a warning, but with the `for` the `$i` will always be set so I guess not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code at starting of for loop

```
if($i == 0)
    continue;
```

This skip first iteration of you loop

your code will be

```
echo "<tr>";
 for($i = 0; $i < (int)count($fieldvalues); $i++){
 if($i == 0)
    continue;
 echo "<td>" . $fieldvalues[$i] . "</td>";
 if($i % 4 == 0){
 echo "<td><input type='text'></td><td><input type='submit' 
 value='Add to cart'></td></form></tr>";
                } 
 }
```